# Getting Social profiles from iOS 6 Address Book

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, social-networking, ios5

In simulator/iPhone 5, I've some contacts that have been imported from Facebook. Now I'm trying to read those profiles using iPhone address book framework. Unfortunately it doesn't return anything. Below is the code snippet that I'm currently using,

```
ABRecordRef person = ABAddressBookGetPersonWithRecordID(ABAddressBookCreate(), (ABRecordID)recordId)
ABMultiValueRef social = ABRecordCopyValue((__bridge ABRecordRef)person, kABPersonSocialProfileProperty);
//the count of 'social' is empty event there is a Facebook profile is attached to the contact.
if (social) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(social); i++) {
         NSDictionary *socialDict = (NSDictionary *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(social, i);
         NSString* service = [socialDict valueForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonSocialProfileServiceKey];
         NSString* username = [socialDict valueForKey:(NSString *)kABPersonSocialProfileUsernameKey];
         NSLog(@"service... %@, username... %@", service, username);
    }
}
CFRelease(social);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that permission is granted to access the Address Book?

Comment: Yes, I was able to receive all phone numbers except social profiles.

Comment: Are social profile fields exists in contacts? Have you checked? I think that it's empty, because you imported it.